# Lodash template return function says data undefined

Tags: javascript, templates, lodash

I am working on a code gen tool, and I am using Lodash to template the output files.  When I try running the resultant function from `_.template(XXX)` I get

> "AppData" (the name of the template variable) is not defined.

I have tried to call `temp` below with and without the AppData variable and both give me

> "ReferenceError: AppData is not defined"

```
templates.forEach((template) => {
      let temp = _.template(template, { AppData: AppData });
      output = temp(AppData);
    });
```

This is the AppData object:

```
let AppData = { clientId: clientId,
                appId: applicationId,
                intents: ['Testing1',
                          'Testing2',
                          'Testing3',
                          'Testing4'
                         ]};
```

Here is one of the 3 templates:

```
<% _.each(AppData.intents, function( intent ){ %>
<transition event="<%=intent%>" target="<%=intent%>">
<state id="<%=intent%>">
<onentry>
<assign location="href_answer" expr="tfs.getKBAPIUrl(DNIS, environment, '<%=intent%>')"/>
<assign location="reason" expr="'<%=intent%>'"/>
<script><![CDATA[presentAnswer(href_answer,reason);]]></script>
</onentry>
  </state>
<% }) %>
```

Stack is not letting me post the output, but it's the function representing the finished template.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should step back and get the lodash to first do the templating first and then once you get the templating work, then introduce more complexity...

```
var tfsStr = document.querySelector('#tfs-template').textContent;
var compiled = _.template(tfsStr, {
  intents: AppData.intents,
  _: _
});
```

I did a little [codepen](http://codepen.io/headwinds/pen/YZRmML?editors=1010) to test the templating

Answer (score 0):

After much head smashing, I realized a simple issue.

I was passing the object incorrectly, and the templates were looking for the wrong thing.  In the templates I removed my AppData. object notation and updated the code to look like this.  The templates picked up the values correctly.

```
templates.forEach((template) => {
  let temp = _.template(template);
  output += temp(AppData);
});
```

A bit of a rookie mistake, first time using Lodash.